# issue in table creation inside wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have installed a Custom-Database-Table plugin in my wordpress. So that i can easily manipulate with database or tables whenever i have need for this but after trying continuously unable to see this plugin database in phpmyadmin. Though wordpress database is displaying correct in XAMPP sever's phpmyadmin but unable to show the installed plugin database.

After installing this plugin i have also activate this plugin.Actually my problem is that , at the time of activation of plugin it's not showing any error and that'a why i am not able to understand where and why i am worng.

Please help to getting this issue.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please on wp_debug from your wp-config.php file - WP_DEBUG(true)
then check it will show error what exactly happen behind

Comment: My best guess would be that the table does not exists.

Comment: @ Manthan Dave.. WP_DEBUG is true.I have already checked it before.Is there any other way to check it?

Comment: put this code in index.php or plugin config file may be it will show the errors to you - ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Manthan Dave.. still it's not showing any error. can you please tell me, is there any other way to display the database of wordpress plugin ?

Comment: But first you need to check is there plugin table is exist or not in your database, so please check that

Comment: No, it doesn't exist in database. ;(

Comment: I am not sure what you expect to see. This plugin allows you to create new tables in the database. In your OP you are saying you are not seeing the custom database. This plugin does NOT create a custom database. It allows you to create custom tables in your WordPress database and manipulate them from the admin.